# Which virtualized target is recommended for newbie on vm-obfuscation?

Tags: obfuscation, crackme, virtualizers

I'm newbie on virtualized code obfuscation. I can break many features to avoid debugging/reversing and packer/protector (even Themida, without vm option), but I'm not good at virtualized code.

Though I made own code virtualizing obfuscation tool, It's too hard to break other virtualized code framework.(e.g: Themida, VMProtect, Code Virtualizer)

So, I decided to break easy target to get an insight that makes me be good at virtual cpu framework. but I can't find any good target for newbie. Could you recommend easy target(crackme or protector) for newbie?

If possible, I want target of which virtualized-code was translated from x86 assembly code.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [crackmes.de](http://crackmes.de/archive/), especially *level 6*, like [this one](http://crackmes.de/users/zerocoder/crackme_v10.0/), or [this one](http://crackmes.de/users/solar_designer/solar/).